# Why is translate working and not sed for line feed

Tags: string, bash, sed, replace, tr

I would like to replace linefeed by something else like #

I have tried sed but \n doesn't work and \x0a as well

I got file z1

```
cat z1|hd

00000000  30 0a 61 0a 0a 31 0a 62  0a 0a 32 0a 63 0a        |0.a..1.b..2.c.|
```

and if i try

```
cat z1|sed $'s/\x30//g'
```

everything is fine

But it doesn't work for line feed in sed, just an error message

```
cat z1|sed $'s/\x0a//g'
```

If i try

```
cat z1| tr "\n" "#"|hd
```

everything is fine for linefeed

Why is sed not working for linefeed ?

Comment: Because by default, `sed` splits the text into lines with the LF char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;y/\n/#/' file
```

This slurps the file into memory, then translate `\n`'s to `#`'s

Alternative:

```
sed -z 'y/\n/#/' file
```

Comment: No, the first command should work on all posix compatible `sed`s. The second is only for GNU sed - it supports the `-z` option.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` will not match literal newline, because commands in `sed` are delimetered by a newline. So `sed`, when parses the command, sees a newline and assumes it is the end of this command. And then `sed` errors with a syntax error, because `s/` is an invalid command, the `s` needs three delimeter characters, `/` here. More specifically, [posix sed documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) explicitly forbids embedding literal newline in `BRE` inside `s/BRE/replacement/flags` command: `A literal <newline> shall not be used in the BRE of a context address or in the substitute function`.

Outside from that, `sed` parses the input line after line, but ignores the newline from input and automatically appends a newline when printing. So even if you did `s/\n/#/` it wouldn't do anything, because there is no newline in the input. You can: append all the lines into hold space, then switch hold space with pattern space and then substitute newlines. This is the solution presented by @potong.

Answer (score 0):

There are `sed` versions which accept `\n` or hex character codes but this is not portable. If you can't use `tr` (why not?) then maybe explore Perl, which of course is not standard at all, but available practically everywhere; and because there is only one implementation, it will work everywhere Perl is available.

```
perl -pe 'y/\n/#/' z1
```

Also note the absence of a [useless `cat`.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: "Perl is not standard" Do you mean it is not ratified by a governing standards body?

Comment: Yeah, `sed` is standardized in POSIX etc whereas Perl is not. Ironically, the standard does not specify a particular behavior for this specific use case.